# After onClick page redirect to page but with displaying deleted data?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

After i click on the button to delete it calls the method DeleteFavorite but when it redirecttoAction it still shows the deleted value on the page Favorites.

How do i refresh the page Favorites to show the correct data?

Delete

```
function DeleteID(favID) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("DeleteFavorite", "Home")",
        data: { favID: favID },
        dataType: "json"


    })
}

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteFavorite(int favID)
        {
            if(favID > 0){
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Favorites WHERE id={0} ", favID);

             TempData["RecordUpdated"] = "Record Deleted.";

            return RedirectToAction("Favorites");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `RedirectToAction` with an Ajax call, won't redirect the user anywhere because you're not engaging the default lifecycle of a full page post/refresh, you're only making a side call via ajax, which effectively acts independently of the rest of the webpage.

I'd say there are 3 standard options you can take:

1. You can return json instead, with an anonymous object, and in the success of the ajax call, force a page refresh through javascript by changing the `window.href` property.
2. You can in the success of the ajax call, use javascript to remove the html that represented the object you've just deleted.

   ```
   $.ajax({

       type:"POST",
       url: "@Url.Action("DeleteFavorite", "Home")",
       data: { favID: favID },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (){
       //window.href.replace("@Url.Action()") //I'm not sure on the syntax here off hand it's been a while since I've done this

       //or 

      //use jquery/javascript to remove the html as in step 2.
   }
   ```

   })
3. You can not use ajax, and use a normal form post, which sends the page back to the server in a normal Post, and your current controller code will work as is.

You do this by using the Html helper for forms if you're using .net Framework and the form tag helper if you're using .net Core.

```
@using (Html.BeingForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.POST)
{

<button name="Action" value="@item.PrimaryKey" type="submit" >Delete</button>
}
or
<form asp-action="ActionName" asp-controller="ControllerName" >

    <button name="Action" value="@item.PrimaryKey" type="submit" >Delete</button>
</form>
```

If you're going route number 3 and you have a list of items, then you might want to look at one of my previous answers about model binding with lists.

I'd advise you investigate each approach and decide which one you're wanting to implement based on the feel of your website that you want to achive.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.